# Elements overlapping on responsive design

Tags: css, wordpress, responsive-design

The design I'm working on (apart from the desktop version) has been thinking for a 480px x 720px resolution, but it suppose to show ok on smaller devices. I'm having a lot of problems with the elements on it, they are all overlapping.

[This is how it should look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YEhto.png)

[And this is how it looks on a smaller resolution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F55BA.png)

My main concern right now is with the overlapping elements, I know I may need to adjust some other things using media queries, but I don't want to continue until I fix this:

- correctly position the menu (as it moves and finally disappear).
- Show the full masked image.
- Prevent buttons (images) from overlapping.
- Prevent text from leaving div.

As I believe that I have a very confusing mix/absence of position and display elements on my css.

Relevant code:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
/*for the menu*/
.site-header {
display: block !important;
}
.sidebar-toggle { //the menu bar-icon properly
right: 390px !important; // I needed to do this because it was originally on the right side (im working on the Magnus theme in wordpress)
display: table;
position: absolute;
float:left;
}

/*for showing the masked image*/
.content-area {  //the div that contains the "A" masking the image
overflow: hidden; //without this scroll appears
}
h1.masking-a {
display: block;
position: relative;
}

/*for the text and image buttons*/
.square-footer { //the container div
position: fixed;
}
.square-footer-text {
position: fixed;
}
.square-footer-text p {
position: relative;
text-align: center !important;
}
.square-footer img {
position: fixed;
}
}
```

Comment: Can you share some of the HTML as well? Even better if you can provide a jsFiddle or some live code reproducing your issue. That will help speed up the troubleshooting process. Without seeing anything else, your CSS does look to have some confusing rules, for example setting `position absolute` and `float left` on the same element.